# How to plot functions of this form? $x^7-\sqrt y=$ constant +$\log(x)+e^y$ (of an equation between $x$ and $y$)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I need to know how to plot any kind of equation between $x$ and $y$ without solving it for $y$.
For example, for $x^2+y^2=1$ I need the plot without knowing that $y=\pm \sqrt {1-x^2}$.

Comment: are you trying in matlab or excel?

Comment: no,no. I need to do this by hand, not with a program :). If I needed that I would have tried [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=plot%3A%20x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D1).

Comment: I would pick a range for x and compute the value of y for each of those values of x. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's almost impossible w/o a computer.

Comment: @BinaryBurst: Do you have a log table or slide rule with you?